# Nested template is not being rendered : Golang

Tags: go, go-html-template

The application in perl calls the header in golang via SSI to render the banner.
In golang the header template {gold_shop_header.shtml} inculdes another template {reputation_level_info.html}. The issue is that the contents of the included template are not being rendered.

Code for reference:

```
gold_shop_header.shtml

  {{define "Gold Banner"}}
    .
    .
     <div class="text-center mt-3">
        <span class="fs-12 font-default cursor-default">
              {{ Loc .Lang "Reputation" }}
              {{ template "reputation_level" . }}
        </span>
     </div>
     .
     .
   {{ end }}


reputation_level_info.html

    {{define "reputation_level"}}
    <i class="icon-help-alt ml-5">
     <div class="absolute text-left" style="">
        <div class="relative hover-reputation-lib">
            <div class="relative w-100p">
                <div class="fs-18 mt-5">{{ Loc .Lang "Reputation Levels" }}</div>

                <table class=" mt-10 fs-8 table-repsys" >
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="bold">
                            <th>{{ Loc .Lang "Badges" }}</th>
                            <th>{{ Loc .Lang "Name" }}</th>
                            <th>{{ Loc .Lang "Points" }}</th>
                        </tr>

                        {{ range .RepLevels }}
                        <tr class="{{ .Class}}">
                            <td>
                                <span class="badges-lib {{ .ImageName}}"></span>
                            </td>

                            {{ if eq .Badges "off" }}
                            <td>
                                {{ .Badges }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ if .UpperBound }}
                                    {{ .LowerBound }} - {{ .UpperBound }} Points
                                {{ else }}
                                    &gt; {{ .LowerBound }} Points
                                {{ end }}
                            </td>
                            {{ else }}
                                <td colspan="2">{{ Loc ..Lang "Reputation Off" }}</td>
                            {{ end }}
                        </tr>
                        {{ end }}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</i>
{{ end }}




gen.go

   var reputationTemplatePath = "/var/ssi/banner/gold/reputation_level_info.html"

    _goldShopReputationTemplateBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(reputationTemplatePath)
    if err != nil {
      log.Panic("err", "error reading template", err)
    }

    var goldShopRepString = string(_goldShopReputationTemplateBytes)

    var headerTemplatePath = "/var/ssi/banner/gold/gold_shop_header.shtml"

    _goldShopHeaderTemplateBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(headerTemplatePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("err", "error reading template", err)
    }

    var goldShopHeaderString = string(_goldShopHeaderTemplateBytes)

    var templatesString [] string

    GoldShopHeaderTemplate, err = template.New("Gold Shop  Header").Funcs(GetTemplateFunctionMap()).
      Parse(goldShopHeaderString)
     if err != nil {
       log.Panic("err", "error parsing template", err)
     }
    GoldShopHeaderTemplate.Parse(goldShopRepString)


htmlBuffer := bytes.NewBufferString("")
template_exec_err := GoldShopHeaderTemplate.Execute(htmlBuffer, argsHeader)
```

Please suggest what is wrong. I am new to golang. The included template is not being rendered. also, for the main template if I remove the {{ define " Gold Banner"}} statement does it get rendered, if I include this statement nothing gets rendered.
No error is reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to reassign the `GoldShopHeaderTemplate` after you parsed `goldShopRepString`

This line:

```
GoldShopHeaderTemplate.Parse(goldShopRepString)
```

Should Be:

```
GoldShopHeaderTemplate, err := GoldShopHeaderTemplate.Parse(goldShopRepString)
```